# Bootstrap multiple select with only CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css, select, multi-select

I can't find anywhere a simple multi-select using css, this is how select looks when attr multiple added

[image]

I need to build on top of it more functionality and use it as an angular component, I'm building an angular library and I don't want it to depend on any other plugin

Comment: can you share your html & css?
there is an example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you don't want to use any plugins! it simplifies the issue instead of writing too many lines, 
I advise to use (chosen plugin) and here is an example of it

[chosen plugin (multiple select)](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Comment: I need to build on top of it more functionality and use it as an angular component, I'm building an angular library and I don't want it to depend on any other plugin

Comment: aha, mm so you can search for angular components, look at this for example 
http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main